# R - Warning: unable to access index for repository

Tags: r

Here is my OS details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux starbuck 3.2.0-92-generic #131-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 16:16:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my R version:

```
$ R --version
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
```

Here is my `.Rprofile`:

```
options("repos" = c(CRAN = "https://cran.r-project.org"))
```

Now when I open R and try to list the available packages I get:

```
 > available.packages()
 Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib
 Package Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances
 License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs MD5sum
 NeedsCompilation File Repository
```

Comment: Works without any problems here. Please try it again. And add the output of `lsb_release -a` to your question.

Comment: I had installed the package from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/. Apparently, this package did not/does not build with `libcurl` (as `capabilities('libcurl')` returns `FALSE`). Thus, I cannot hit HTTPS CRAN sources. My next question then is, how can I install R with libcurl support?

Comment: @mikeycgto it seems you did get an answer from the [R-sig-Debian mail list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2015-November/002481.html). Care to add it as an answer here?